# How to deal with large amount of resource files outside Hugo’s dir sturcture

Tags: resources, symlink, hugo

I have a bunch of video files on NFS share (500GB+). Linking to them from `static` directory gives error: `symlinks not allowed in this filesystem`. Linking from `content` directory causes Hugo to try to copy them all to RAM memory. What is the right way to give Hugo an access to the files without copying them.

Comment: For anyone who has the same problem: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-deal-with-large-amount-of-resource-files-outside-hugos-dir-sturcture/22273/2. So it is better to serve files outside Hugo, and embed videos in Hugo site. In my case inside LAN, I simply serve a video directory with Python's embedded HTTP server and point in Hugo to this URL.